# Mysql slow imports after months

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a Debian 8 server with mysql server 5.6 and I have huge problems with performance after months using it with db imports every day. Just after reinstall SO mysql imports are fast, around 9-10m with 250Gb SSD Samsung EVO 850.

After 3 months, db imports needs 13-14m. After 6 months, 20m. After 1 year 50m, at this point I reinstall SO and imports come back to 9-10m

Database increases his size with 1mb every month, so db size isn't the problem.

**I can't understand why** (I can't reinstall SO every 3-4 months..)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the "import" statement.

Comment: What are the indexes and index size? Inserts do increase over time as indexes grow. I've also found importing is much faster with no indexes and then doing alter table add index after the import.

Comment: My thoughts are there is an issue with index size. Try checking the index sizes over time. Also, check if you have space for indexes or not.